# Bottom Navigation Bar Disappears When Navigating to New Page

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui

I have created a `BottomNavigationBar` with my app, but when I navigate to a new page by clicking on `Profile` the `BottomNavigationBar` goes away. I have been working on this for hours and I am about to give up lol. Any ideas?

`app.dart`

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        '/home':(context) => HomePage(),
        '/activity':(context) => ActivityPage(),
        '/profile':(context) => ProfilePage(),
      },
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home_filled), label: 'Home',),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.track_changes), label: 'Activity'),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: 'Profile'),
            ],
            onTap: (index) {
              switch (index) {
                case 0:
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
                break;
                case 1:
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/activity');
                break;
                case 2:
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/profile');
                break;
              }
            },
          ),
          body: MaterialApp.router(
            builder: EasyLoading.init(),
            theme: ThemeData(
              appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(color: Color(0xFF13B9FF)),
              colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
                accentColor: const Color(0xFF13B9FF),
              ),
            ),
            routerDelegate: AutoRouterDelegate(
              _appRouter,
              navigatorObservers: () => [AppRouteObserver()],
            ),
            routeInformationProvider: _appRouter.routeInfoProvider(),
            routeInformationParser: _appRouter.defaultRouteParser(),
            localizationsDelegates: const [
              AppLocalizations.delegate,
              GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            ],
            supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried clicking on different pages and still did not get the navbar to follow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `Navigator.pushNamed` because you are navigating to a new page, and on the new page, there is no `BottomNavigationBar`. You can use `PageView` and assign a `PageController` to it. After that, you can re-write `onTap` of `BottomNavigationBar` and control the `PageView` via `PageController` you assigned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it with this library. https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar_v2/versions/4.0.3

```
pushNewScreenWithRouteSettings(
    context,
    settings: RouteSettings(name: MainScreen.routeName),
    screen: MainScreen(),
    withNavBar: true,
    pageTransitionAnimation: PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
);
```

withNavBar : true -> can be controlled by this

Comment: Do I remove the code I have now, or just add the code above?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using **Navigator.pushReplacement()** instead of the **.push()** method.

I have this class in my main.dart file:

```
class NavBarPage extends StatefulWidget {   NavBarPage({Key? key, this.initialPage, this.page}) : super(key: key);

  final String? initialPage;   final Widget? page;

  @override   _NavBarPageState createState() => _NavBarPageState(); }
```

Then, when I need to navigate and persist my GNav bar or the standard bar,I use **Navigator.pushReplacement()**.

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => NavBarPage(
                      initialPage: 'YourScreenName',
                    ),
                  ),
                );
```

I hope this can help someone :)